# How to a fetch particular value from PHP to Java Script via AJAX and keep the div always in the bottom?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have asked this question before also, but the solution didn't work. I have a messaging website. I fetch the messages via AJAX with Java Script that runs per 1 second. The problem is that it fetch all the values from starting to end. So I thought of passing the last message ID via AJAX. But I don't know how to use that value in the Java Script, so that I can use it to fetch the messages which will be more than it.

Also I want the div to be in it's bottom position, until the user scrolls it. And whenever a new message is fetched the div should automatically reach the bottom.

Here is my CSS, HTML, Java Script and AJAX code:

```
<style>
.readarea{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="readarea" id="readarea">

<!--Messages is to be displayed here.-->

</div>

<div class="inputarea">
<textarea placeholder="Type your message" style="width: 800px; overflow: hidden" id="msg"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" style="padding: 10px 25px" id="sendmsg">
</div>
</body>

<script>

function fetchdata(){
var lm =                                        //last message ID
var cuser =                                     //user ID of the 1st person
var ouser =                                     //user ID of the 2nd person
 $.ajax({
  url: "readmessagesprocess.php",
  type: "POST",
  data : {cuser:cuser, ouser:ouser, lm:lm},
  success: function(read){
    $("#readarea").html(read);
  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(fetchdata,1000);
});


</script>
```

Here is my PHP code to fetch the messages:

```
<?php

$cuser = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['cuser']);
$ouser = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ouser']);
$lastmessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lm']);

$sql = "SELECT id, fromid,message,toid FROM messages WHERE ((fromid={$cuser} AND toid={$ouser}) OR (fromid={$ouser} AND toid={$cuser})) AND id>{$lastmessage}";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or ("Query Failed");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  if($row["fromid"]==$cuser){
    echo "<div class='cuser'>".$row["message"]."</div>";
  }else{
    echo "<div class='ouser'>".$row["message"]."</div>";
  }
  $lm = $row["id"];                                                       //last message id
}
?>
```

Here I want the $lm("lm") to use in Java Script as the last message ID (var lm) and the rest of the code to concatenate in the . Also I want this div to be in the bottom part  when the page loads or new message is fetched.

Comment: where is the last message ID available on the page?

Comment: in the java script. var lm

Comment: What? i mean where are you fetching the ID from

Comment: Check the PHP code variable $lm.

Comment: Thats where you are passing the ID. YOu need to have the ID first in the html to pass it to php through js

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: You need to provide a bit more explanation. What is the userId's for? are users logged in? Where are they coming from?

Comment: Users are logged in. But I have not provided it yet (I can manage that). The users ID are for identifying who are the two  persons between whom the messages are been sent and received.

Comment: your technology is very outdated. sockets are much better for this sort of job. if you can't run a nodejs server and are willing to live with the delays, overhead and insecurities of your approach you should at least start passing the data from backend to frontend via JSON - then having an array of messages that are transformed into elements in the DOM on the client side and some information bits, like the last messageId in the reply data package is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have turned your code into a working chat-snippet. I am using a slightly quirky method for mimicking an external PHP server, that would be handling the actual chat data in a database. I realize that parts of my script will seem terse and even cryptic. So, here are a few rudimentary explanations:

The code starts with an IIFE, an "immediatel invoked functional expression". This expression provides a scope for setting up a "chat database", i. e. the object `msg` with a first message in it. This `msg` object is visible for the functions `setmsg()` and `getmsg()` which I also define in the same scope through `w[setm]=...` (`w` and `setm` are arguments of the IIFE and set to `window` and `'setmsg'` when the IIFE is called) and `w[getm]=...`.

The function `qs()` is simply a shorthand notation for calling `document.querySelector()` which I find a bit clunky to hanlde. The optional argument `el` makes it possible to search within an element context. Without it the search starts on the document level.

Oh, yes, and the `blb()` function is a little trick I picked up [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290948/2610061). Stackoverflow does not provide a way of doing CORS Ajax calls and this method is a workaround that allows at least `GET` calls (you cannot `POST` to the `URL.createObjectURL()` object). The functions `getmsg()` and `setmsg()` use this `blb()` utility to mimick an external server. They return an object that can be used in place of a server-URL that is *usually* supplied in the jQuery Ajax call.

```js
// for AJAX testing: set up a setter, a getter and a utility "querySelector" function qs:
((w,setm,getm,qs)=>{ 
 const blb=da=>URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(da)],{type: "text/json"}));
 const msg=[{cuser:'abc', ouser:'def', txt:'the first message'}];
 w[setm]=da=>(msg.push(da), blb({lm:msg.length}));  // setter ajax function
 w[getm]=lm=>blb(msg[lm]);                          // getter ajax function
 w[qs]=(s,el)=>(el||document).querySelector(s);     // query Selector with context 
})(window,'setmsg','getmsg','qs');

function fetchdata(){
 let lm = +(qs("li:last-child")||{dataset:{id:-1}}).dataset.id + 1;
 $.ajax({
  url: getmsg(lm),           //  "readmessagesprocess.php",
  type: "GET",               //  "POST", data : ...
  success: dat=>dat.cuser && //  action ONLY if dat.cuser exists!
    $("#readarea").append(`<li data-id="${lm}">${lm}: ${dat.cuser} says: ${dat.txt}</li>`)
 });
}

var intFD; // setInterval handle
const scanStart=()=>(intFD=setInterval(fetchdata,1000));
$(document).ready(function(){
 scanStart();
 qs('#resume').onclick=scanStart;
 qs('#stop')  .onclick=()=>clearInterval(intFD);
 qs('#send')  .onclick=()=>{
   $.getJSON(setmsg({cuser:'cars10m',txt:qs('#msg').value}), 
      function(da){console.log('server response: message count='+da.lm)} );
   qs('#msg').value="";
 }
})
```

```css
.readarea{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
button, [type=submit] {padding: 10px 25px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="readarea" id="readarea"></ul>

<div class="inputarea"><p>... and this is the input area.</p>
<textarea placeholder="Type your message" style="width: 800px; overflow: hidden" id="msg"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" id="send" value="send"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="resume">resume</button>
</div>
```

A few word on how the chat system works: the regular message scan starts once the page is loaded with `scanStart()`. This function in turn calls `fetchdata()` which will try to find the `id` of the latest post that is already shown on the browser. I used the CSS selector `"li:last-child"` for this purpose. Unlike in the original version I am using `<li>` elements for each post here. And the above selector will get the *last* one posted. I then grab its id and put it in `lm` (`lm` is always the message index of the last message found in `msg` *plus 1*) and start the `$.ajax()` call to `getmsg()` with `lm`.

The buttons `[stop]` and `[resume]` can be used to stop and resume the message scanning.

Answer (score 0):

this shouldn't be done via AJAX, but with **sockets**. have your favourite websearch give you results for "**nodejs chat**"